# Folium plot GeoJSON polygon with fill color based on custom values

Tags: python, geopandas, choropleth, folium

I have polygons with lat/long values associated with identifiers in a `GeoDataFrame` as shown below. Consider an example with two identifiers `A` and `B`, polygon `A` has three points and `B` has four points, their lat/long values are as shown below. Corresponding to each point (lat/long), I also have an associated numeric value as shown in the last column.

```
id    geometry                                                                         values
A   POLYGON((lat_A_1 long_A_1, lat_A_2 long_A_2, lat_A_3 long_A_3))                    10,12,13
B   POLYGON((lat_B_1 long_B_1, lat_B_2 long_B_2, lat_B_3 long_B_3, lat_B_4 long_B_4))  4,8,16,20
```

I iterate over the GeoDataFrame and plot these polygons on the map using this code

```
geo_j = folium.GeoJson(data=geo_j,
                       style_function={ 
                           'fillColor': 'blue'
                       })
```

Is there a way that I can fill the polygon with a custom colormap based on the column `values` in the GeoDataFrame, such as red for 0-5, blue for 6-10 and green for 11-20. How can this be done?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which color would you assign for Polygon B? Its `values` is `4, 8, 6, 20`. There is a number for each color range.

Comment: I want to define a colormap like red for 0-5, blue for 6-10 and green for 11-20. Using this, for polygon B, I want area around vertex 1 to be red (for value 4), area around vertex 2 and 3 to be blue (for values 8,6) and area around vertex 4 to be green (for value 20). The interior of the polygon should be filled progressively be extrapolating vertex colors using the colormap. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Do you need something like this (for a triangle): https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4fgj.jpg

Comment: Yes, that would be the required objective here.

Comment: Maybe like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919669/folium-geojson-style-function-not-working-as-i-want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the solution that I came up with:

```
import matplotlib
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# gdf: One's own geopandas geoDataFrame
# colname: name of the gdf to be plotted into the Folium Map

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = gdf.total_bounds

centroidx = np.mean([xmin, xmax])
centroidy = np.mean([ymin, ymax])

map1 = folium.Map(
    location=[centroidy, centroidx],
    tiles='cartodbpositron',
    zoom_start=6,
)

cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('viridis')

vmin = gdf[colname].min()
vmax = gdf[colname].max()


norm = matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, linthresh=0.1)

def fetchHexFromValue(value):
  NormedValue = norm(value)
  RGBAValue = cmap(NormedValue)
  HEXValue = matplotlib.colors.to_hex(RGBAValue)
  return HEXValue



for idx, r in gdf.iterrows():

    lat = r["geometry"].centroid.y
    lon = r["geometry"].centroid.x
    folium.Marker(location=[lat, lon],
                  popup='idx:{0} <br> {1}: {2}'.format(idx,
                                                       colname, 
                                                       r[colname])
    ).add_to(map1)

gdf.explore(colname, cmap="viridis", m=map1)

map1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `explore()` method, of GeoDataFrame object.

In the argument cmap you can set a `cmap`; in the agg `scheme` you can choose a choropleth classification scheme (or create it manually, i.e.: *UserDefined*); and through `k` agg set the number of classes.

This method worked fine for me with gpd version == 10.0.2

If cannot find the method, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539995/geodataframe-object-has-no-attribute-explore

Comment: could you please provide a MWE?

Comment: Here is the ```explore()``` method documentation:
https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore.html